# template std.file.readText cannot deduce function from argument types !()(File)

Tags: d

I am trying to use the [readText](https://dlang.org/library/std/file/read_text.html) function:

```
import std.stdio;
import std.file;

string xmlName = r"D:\files\123.xml";
File file;

void main()
{
    writeln("Edit source/app.d to start your project.");
    file = File(xmlName, "r");
    string file_text = file.readText;
}
```

I am getting an error:

```
Error: template std.file.readText cannot deduce function from argument types !()(File), candidates are:
C:\D\dmd2\windows\bin\..\..\src\phobos\std\file.d(499,3):        std.file.readText(S = string, R)(auto ref R name) if (isSomeString!S && (isInputRange!R && !isInfinite!R && isSomeChar!(ElementType!R) || is(StringTypeOf!R)))
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`readText` takes a string argument, being the file name to read from. Since you've opened the file with `File(xmlName, "r")`, you should be using the methods defined in [`std.stdio.File`](https://dlang.org/library/std/stdio/file.html).

It seems what you want is to read the entirety of the file contents into a string. In this case, I suggest replacing the two last lines in your `main` function with `string file_text = readText(xmlName);`

Comment: why `readText` is placed outside `std.file`? Could you explain?

Comment: It isn't - `readText` is in `std.file`. `File`, however, is in `std.stdio`, and I can see how that can be confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to use the *std.file*'s readText(), you need to slighly modify your code:

```
import std.stdio;
import std.file;

string xmlName = "D:/files/123.xml";

void main() {
  writeln("Edit source/app.d to start your project.");
  string file_text = file.readText(xmlName);
}
```

Notice that we no longer create an instance of a File as it is not needed here...